Why every nonzero ideal in principal ideal domain is free and projective?
According to Hungeford Algebra book, "We have seen that every nonzero ideal I in a principal ideal domain D is invertible.
Furthermore I is isomorphic to D as a D-module (see Theorem IV.l.5(i».
Thus I is a free and hence projective D-module. This result also holds in arbitrary
integral domains." (p.403)
I couldn't understand why I is free.

Just do it by definition, construct a basis of the ideal. It is very easy.

By definition of a principal ideal ring, $I=(\alpha)$ for some $\alpha\in R$. Because $R$ is also a domain, if $\alpha$ is nonzero (i.e. if $I$ is nonzero) then the map $R\to I$ which is multiplication by $\alpha$ is an isomorphism of modules, so $I\cong R$ as an $R$-module and is in particular free, projective.
This isomorphism is noncanonical since $\alpha$ is usually not uniquely determined by $I$.
If $I$ is zero, it is still free and projective for trivial reasons.
